# Combine multivalue field rows with copy of same multvalue field

Tags: 8, theming, entities, display-suite

Having a list of pdfs using pdfpreview for image-preview I want to add an additional formatted text-field to this ouput.
That's why I've created a copy of this field with a different formatter (e.g. rendered entity).

As this is a multivalue field I want to combine the values means having the new text-field underneath every preview-picture instead of having all preview pictures first and all rendered entities afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution via media entities and "media pdf thumbnail"